# I need some service to run node server, i mean not just "nodejs server.js"

Tags: node.js, webserver

I am a PHP programmer and trying to learn node.js, but I'm little bit confused on first steps.

PHP may be run as a module of Apache or Nginx or whatever. Of course it has built-in server, but no one will even try run serious project this way. Normal server should return status codes, work as a service, provide access control etc.

Please, tell me how node running on internet? Is there a special software or it use built-in server with tones of code to perform all normal server features?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question (I could be wrong), you are looking to run a HTTP server. You can do this using the express.js framework with node.js.